# SetWindowPos doesn't works with some programs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with positioning and moving on-screen keyboard (osk.exe). I used *SetWindowsPos* to do this, but it takes no effect. I also tried use *MoveWindow* instead of *SetWindowsPos* but it takes no effect too. I used *SetWindowsPos* on Mozilla Firefox and it works fine. I have no idea why it only works with some programs.
It is my code:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Sub SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long)

Private Sub ResizeOsk()
Dim retval As Long
Dim OskHandle As Long
OskHandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Klawiatura ekranowa")
SetWindowPos OskHandle, -1, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, &H40
'MoveWindow OskHandle, 500, 400, 1500, 1000, 1
End Sub
```

When I debug the program, variable OskHandle isn't empty.
Maybe is there another solution to solve my problem with positioning on-screen keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Window List for Edge with one tab open to Google.

```
WindowText  ClassName   HWnd    ParentHWnd  ProcessID   ParentProcessID ThreadID    ModuleNameHWin  EXENameProcess
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft Edge  Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow  82182908    45353128    7336    968 3544    «Not Available Error=126»   MicrosoftEdge.exe
    «No Window Text 0»  Spartan ServiceUI XAML-To-Trident Input Routing Window  21627338    82182908    7336    968 1112    «Not Available Error=126»   MicrosoftEdge.exe
    «No Window Text 0»  Spartan XAML-To-Trident Input Routing Window    54593368    82182908    7336    968 1112    «Not Available Error=126»   MicrosoftEdge.exe
        «No Window Text 0»  Spartan Tab XAML-To-Trident Input Routing Window    64488388    54593368    7336    968 1112    «Not Available Error=126»   MicrosoftEdge.exe
            Google  TabWindowClass  30934882    64488388    7992    4380    3564    «Not Available Error=126»   MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe
                CoreInput   Windows.UI.Core.CoreComponentInputSource    57214268    30934882    7992    4380    3564    «Not Available Error=126»   MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe
                «No Window Text 0»  Internet Explorer_Server    64620588    30934882    7992    4380    3564    «Not Available Error=126»   MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe
        «No Window Text 0»  Spartan ServiceUI XAML-To-Trident Input Routing Window  30344376    54593368    7336    968 1112    «Not Available Error=126»   MicrosoftEdge.exe
        «No Window Text 0»  Spartan ServiceUI XAML-To-Trident Input Routing Window  29230712    54593368    7336    968 1112    «Not Available Error=126»   MicrosoftEdge.exe
```

You can't size child windows bigger than the parent window. And it's in relation to the parent window not the desktop window. Your Window is 4 levels down. The second field is the ClassName, as the top window doesn't have a title (well it's the same for all MS Edge running).

This function may help.

> **GetAncestor**
>
> The GetAncestor function retrieves the handle to the ancestor of the
>   specified window.
>
> ```
> HWND GetAncestor(
>   HWND hwnd,    // handle to window
>   UINT gaFlags  // ancestor
> );
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> hwnd  [in] Handle to the window whose ancestor is to be retrieved. If
>   this parameter is the desktop window, the function returns NULL.
>
> gaFlags  [in] Specifies the ancestor to be retrieved. This parameter
>   can be one of the following values.
>
> **Value Meaning**
>   **GA_PARENT** Retrieves the parent window. This does not include the owner, as it does with the GetParent function.
>   **GA_ROOT** Retrieves the root window by walking the chain of parent windows. 
>   **GA_ROOTOWNER** Retrieves the owned root window by walking the chain of parent and owner windows returned by GetParent.
>
> **Return Values** The return value is the handle to the ancestor window.

From Help.

Also Edge is for Users. The browser for automation is Internet Explorer. It is also the browser for automating editing of HTML or for incorporating Browser controls into your app. (note this is vbscript and if you use it in VBA remove the `wscript.sleep` line as VBA can't use that line but it has it's own equiv.

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate2 "www.google.com.au"
ie.visible=true
wscript.sleep 5000
ie.refresh2 
ie.top=0
ie.left=0
ie.height=200
ie.width=100
```

Comment: I tried use GetAncestor in many ways, i can't understand how it excatly works. Anyway, I still can't change position of osk.exe. Could you explain that in my example with On-Screen Keyboard?